# Mysql - Date() seems to be working strange in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I have a `MySQL` table as

```
| id | user_id | steps_date | steps | target | created_at          |
|----|---------|------------|-------|--------|---------------------|
| 1  | 3       | 2017-01-07 | 3000  | 6000   | 2017-01-07 20:45:33 |
| 2  | 3       | 2017-01-09 | 2545  | 6000   | 2017-01-08 22:15:47 |
| 3  | 3       | 2017-01-10 | 5687  | 6000   | 2017-01-08 21:11:22 |
```

The `steps_date` column is of datatype `date` and `created_at` is `timestamp`.

And, I am firing a query to get records for `steps_date >= 2017-01-07` and `steps_date <= 2017-01-09` using query:

```
SELECT * FROM user_steps_data
WHERE user_id = 3 
AND DATE(steps_date) >= '2017-01-07' 
AND DATE(steps_date) <= '2017-01-09';
```

And it is returning only record with `steps_date=2017-01-09`, not with `steps_date=2017-01-07`. Why?

Comment: `DATE(steps_date) <= '2016-01-09'` this should be `DATE(steps_date) <= '2017-01-09'` ... you accidentally used 2016 for 2017.

Comment: Oops!! typo. Again, still it is returning only record for step date ```2017-01-09```, not ```2017-01-07```. Why?

Comment: Use [`BETWEEN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) for that sort of query and it will avoid this sort of mistake. `steps_date BETWEEN '2017-01-07' AND '2017-01-09'`

Comment: Just use `steps_date >= '2017-01-07' AND steps_date <= '2016-01-09'` , no need to cast to date.

Comment: use between SELECT * FROM user_steps_data
WHERE user_id = 3 and DATE(steps_date) between  '2017-01-07' 
AND  '2017-01-09';

Comment: Strange!! but without casting it is working well.. Thanks @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @Dev there is no reason to cast since the field is *already* a DATE. There is nothing strange to this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `BETWEEN`

```
SELECT * FROM user_steps_data WHERE user_id = 3 and steps_date between '2017-01-07' AND '2017-01-09';
```

Comment: The important fix here is that no cast is needed since the field is already a `DATE`. The cast would prevent MySQL from using any underlying indexes

Answer (score 0):

Try to use MySQL
 `BETWEEN` Condition. It is used to retrieve values within a range in a `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` statement.

```
SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE order_date BETWEEN CAST('2014-02-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2014-02-28' AS DATE);
```